# Don't make changes to user data Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using user data when using selenium chrome webdriver which I have running on a cronjob:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("./chromedriver_setup/chrome-data")

service = Service("./chromedriver_setup/chromedriver") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
```

After each job, the user data is changed, is there a way to remove these changes between each job?

Comment: hmm, there is no way easy way to do that AFAIK, you may have to copy the original profile to third profile say C and use the same for each of your job.

Comment: This is a nice work around actually, just replace it after each job with the original data.